# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fmotors_fms.block_node_type' doesn't exist:

Tags: database

This was working fine last night but when i login to my computer again I got this error now. What is this table `{block_node_type}` I cant find it in the database but it is in the drupal code in node.module. PLease help

Answer (score 1):

If it was working last night, and now it doesn't and the table is missing, then the table has been deleted/renamed, or the database is partially corrupted. There isn't any other logical explanation.

As you rightly say that table is installed, unconditionally, by the node module upon installation of Drupal (see [`node_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.install/function/node_schema/7)).

If the table is really gone then your only option is to restore the DB from a backup; or if there was no data in that table, just manually create it (or copy from another Drupal install).